# Remeber iFram SRC when refreshing parent page

Tags: php, iframe, refresh, src

I have an intranet I am building, and am learning web languages as I go.

I have a basic html/php page that contains an iFrame, which most of my content is loaded into.

I also have a login box that is a popup modal within the main page.
When you fill in this popup and hit login, it refreshes the main page, so that it knows you are logged in, and can display your name etc etc.

However, this means that the iframe SRC also resets to its default.

Is there a way to retain whatever the current SRC of the iframe is, when refreshing the parent page?

Comment: Can we see some code please? Also you don't mention how/when you are changing the iframe's `src` from the "default".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a [session variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to keep the current src.

In your case I would do something like the following:

All pages which are loaded in the `iframe` can contain the code to set the session var.

```
<?php

session_start(); // before any output to the user-agent / browser /screen!!!

$_SESSION['last_visited'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And on the page which displays the iframe you can simply do something like:

```
<?php

session_start(); // before any output to the user-agent / browser /screen!!!

echo '<iframe src="', $_SESSION['last_visited'], '"></iframe>';
```

Regarding your question about saving the URL in the database.

You could do that but I would just save it in a cookie.

Comment: I was thinking it would probably be a session variable. I am currently also using session variables for logins as well.
how would i go about setting the url as a session variable?
perhaps I can also add this into my database to remember the users last visited page as well

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="whatever" method="post">
...
    <input type="hidden" id="iframeSrc" name="iframeSrc"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="addSrc()" value="Log in"/>
</form>

<iframe id="mybox" src="somepage"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
function addSrc() {
   document.getElementById('iframeSrc').value = document.getElementById('mybox').src;
}
```

**PHP**

```
$iframeSrc = $_POST['iframeSrc'];
...
echo "<iframe id=\"mybox\" src=\"$iframeSrc\"></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```